# Variables de entorno Visual Estudio

Tags: vb.net

Estoy desarrollando en `Visual Studio 2015`, pero tengo problemas con algunas variables que al momento de probar deben de tener un *valor(paths, cadenas de conexión, etc)*; y al momento de publicar deberían tener otro que es el de producción. Hay alguna forma para que solo con cambiarle en la compilación a `release mode`, me obtenga las configuraciones adecuadas?

Saludos

Comment: deberias agregar codigo... para ver como esta realizado el mismo

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto 
[Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), puede tratar de mejorar 
su pregunta mirando este link [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada, ya que no cumple con los estándares del sitio, no se lo tome a mal. Saludos

Comment: De donde tomas tus variables?

Comment: Las variables las tomo en un compilado de otro proyecto ej: var path="localpath" lo que desearía es que yo pueda hacer algo parecido a esto if(compilacion==release) path="releasepath".- Tengo algunas ideas de como hacerlo(como poner una variable en el App.config) pero desearía que con solo cambiar la compilación(debug-release) en el entorno de visual studio las calcule sin necesidad de que tuviera que cambiar esta variable en el config